# How can I get oauth token and oauth token secret using the ruby omniauth-twitter gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, omniauth

I setup my app similar to the tutorial here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised. If you cant access it, below is my code

Omniauth controller callback

```
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

user model

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
      user.name = auth.info.name

    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Now I am wondering how do I obtain the authenticated user's oauth token and oauth token secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take a look at the information returned by a certain provider, put this as the first line of your callback controller:

```
raise env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

You'll be able to see that the information you want can be accessed in `auth.credentials.token` and `auth.credentials.secret`.

EDIT: Now that Rails 4 uses the better_errors gem, this method of inspecting the omniauth hash no longer works so well. A better way now is:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```

Comment: `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml` this is so handy . thanks.

Comment: I just use `render json: request.env['omniauth.auth']`